# TypeConversion of a string to bytearray

Tags: c#

I have a string value:

Example:

```
string msg = "array('B', [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6,
7, 9, 8, 6, 7, 9, 7, 6, 6, 8, 11, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 6, 8, 11,
12, 11, 10, 12, 9, 10, 10, 10, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
5, 3, 3, 5, 10, 7, 6, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])"
```

I want to convert this string value to type **byte[]**.

```
private byte[] data;
//after type conversion from string to byte array
Debug.Log("data in byte array is: " + data);
```

Output should be:

> data in byte array is: [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
> 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6,
> 7, 9, 8, 6, 7, 9, 7, 6, 6, 8, 11, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 6, 8, 11,
> 12, 11, 10, 12, 9, 10, 10, 10, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 5, 3, 3, 5, 10, 7, 6, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]

Since the actual *string msg* is a very large value, I want to do this with minimum execution time possible.

Comment: Can you clarify if `string msg = ` is actually part of the string? I assume it is since you've included it in the quote block.

Comment: Your first example is not valid C# (nor is the second really), and at best ambiguous, also I remember something like this question being asked the other day

Comment: the point is you want to "minimum execution time possible." ??

Comment: Not sure about minimum execution time. An easy way would be to match `\[(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*)\]`, split group 1, and then call `byte.Parse()` on the elements. You might want to use something more restrictive than `\d` to guarantee a 0-255 range though.

Comment: @Llama `string msg =` is not part of the string. sorry, I removed the quote block.

Comment: @TimChang Yes, Since the data is really large, I would want to do this with minimum time possible. Possibly without loops etc.

Comment: Carefully looping through exactly once is likely the only way you can do this in the minimum time possible. Other methods would involve loops internally, but give you less control over how many times the data is iterated.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes, Thank you. I did think that was the way, however, I was looking for an inexpensive way in terms of the computation time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a fairly simple parsing problem. We could run up a full parser for the format, but that's probably well beyond your needs.

Let's assume instead that your `msg` is always going to be in the format shown, starting with `"array('B', ["`, ending with `"])"` and having 0 or more comma-separated decimal values. Since any option you choose is going to scan the string at least once, we can design code around doing exactly that.

The actual content contains only 4 types of characters:

- digit (`0`-`9`)
- comma (`,`)
- space ( )
- end-array (`]`)

We can iterate through the characters starting at the first character after the start-array (`[` at offset 11) and do something with each of those character types: ignore it, update the current value, yield the current value and/or exit.

If all of the assumptions are correct then this is a simple process. One scan through the characters, no allocations in the parser itself. Here's a sample:

```cs
IEnumerable<byte> ParseArrayMsg(string msg)
{
    if (!msg.StartsWith("array('B', [") || !msg.EndsWith("])"))
        yield break;
    
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = msg.IndexOf('[') + 1; i < msg.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = msg[i];
        if (c == ',' || c == ']')
        {
            yield return (byte)value;
            value = 0;
            if (c == ']')
                break;
        }
        else if (char.IsDigit(c))
            value = value * 10 + (int)(c - '0');
        else if (c != ' ')
            throw new Exception($"Invalid character '{c}' at index '{i}'.");
    }
}
```

The returned enumerable can then be processed however you like.

Your code won't actually produce the output you want, but this will:

```cs
var data = ParseArrayMsg(msg).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Data in byte array is: [{string.Join(", ", data.Select(b => b.ToString()))}]");
```

```
Data in byte array is: [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9, 8, 6, 7,
9, 7, 6, 6, 8, 11, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 6, 8, 11, 12, 11, 10, 12, 9, 10,
10, 10, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 10, 7, 6, 7, 10, 10,
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like the following:

```
    string yourString= "Your String";  
    // Convert a C# string to a byte array  
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourString);
```